# Parsing through One-To-Many Relationship Results

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm building an app where a user can click on various buttons representing emotions and log their emotional states. The click entities store the time of click.

Right now I have a relationship of **Emotion<------>>Click**

I can get the emotion of a click easily:

```
let emotion = click.value(forKey: ClickAttr.Emotion) as! NSManagedObject
```

I'm confused, however, how I can parse through the clicks of a specific emotion. Right now my code is as following:

```
let clicks = emotion.value(forKey: EmotionAttr.Clicks) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

No matter how I try to cast or iterate through the data I get the error:

```
Could not cast value of type '_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet' (0x7fffbe8bee48) to 'NSArray' (0x7fffbea01ae0).
```

I've read about faulting objects in Core Data relationships but can't figure out how to load that click data. All the other questions/answers I've read on this have either been in Objective-C or have been for outdated versions of Swift.

## Update

I get the same issue if my code is:

```
let clicks: NSSet = emotion.value(forKey: EmotionAttr.Clicks) as! NSSet

Could not cast value of type '_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet' (0x7fffbe8bee48) to 'NSSet' (0x7fffbea02760).
```

Comment: Look up the difference between an Array and an NSSet. Understanding the difference between the two and how to cast between the two will solve your issues. Core Data uses sets while most code uses arrays.

Comment: I get the same issue if my code is:

    let clicks: NSSet = emotion.value(forKey: EmotionAttr.Clicks) as! NSSet.

    Could not cast value of type '_NSFaultingMutableOrderedSet' (0x7fffbe8bee48) to 'NSSet' (0x7fffbea02760).